# If 60 is equal to LX------

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

My nephew many times asks silly questions. Here is one.

> If 60 = LX
>
> Then 80 = X
>    Why?

Can it be?

(His answer was silly too)

Comment: Are these algebraic symbols or Roman numerals?

Comment: Just to save time for anybody thinking "Roman numerals" that doesn't remember what those would be; 60 is LX and 80 is LXXX.

Comment: Is it just me or would the lateral thinking tag feel at home here?

Comment: Good suggestion. Will do it

Comment: How old is your nephew?  Just to help calibrate the silliness level.  :)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so you might want to accept it. If not, some leads on whether people are going in the right direction might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

> 60 = "sixty" = "six t" = 6 * 10 = LX in Roman numerals

so

> 80 = "eighty" = "a t" = 1 * 10 = X in Roman numerals

Answer (score 22):

Maybe?

> If you assume the same rules as roman numerals but redefine the values, so that X=80 and L=20, both statements will be true.

Answer (score 9):

Seems a bit overbroad, maybe the correct answer will fix that. In the meantime, here are a couple of the other kind.

> perfectly fine maths, if L equals 0.75.

or

> looking upside down, it kinda looks like XI = 09, from which it would be sensible to deduce that X = 08

Comment: Not a Mathematics tag though Bass

Comment: And X does not equal 8, it equals 10.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe..

> You need 4 line strokes to write LX, that means you got a score of 100 - 4 * 10 = 60.
>  Hence, because X only needs 2 line strokes, you will get 100 - 2 * 10 = 80.

Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> X means there's a cross in the number, and LX means there's a lack of a cross in the number.
>  In this case, 60, "lacks a cross", and 80 has a "cross" because of the number 8?